# jQuery Steps - custom validation on button click

Tags: jquery, zend-framework

I'm struggling with jquery steps wizard - http://www.jquery-steps.com/
Basically, my app is built on Zend Framework which do also a form validation via ajax.

In previous version, before I decided to use jquery steps plugin, it looked like that:

```
  var form = $('#document-form');
  var step1 = $('#step1');
  var step2 = $('#step2');

  step1.find('button[type="button"].next').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      verifyForm(step1, function() {
          slideToNextStep(step2);
      });
  });


  step2.find('button[type="button"].next').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      verifyForm(step2, function() {
          slideToNextStep(step2);
      });
  });
```

### What I want to achive:

I need to use my own function to validate form - `verifyForm(step, callback);

My current jquery step wizard setup is here:

```
var form = $('#document-form');
form.children('div').steps({
   headerTag: "h3",
   bodyTag: "section",
   transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
   autoFocus: true
});
```

How can I force this plugin to use my function and pass current step to it?

Eventually I could make a hidden button in each step and just trigger it while clicking "next" - if form is ok, then go next, if it is not - abort. However, I have no idea how to do so.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a method for every changed step in jquery steps and call your function right there. You can even call your function at a very specific step if needed.

```
var form = $('#document-form');
form.children('div').steps({
   headerTag: "h3",
   bodyTag: "section",
   transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
   autoFocus: true,
   onStepChanged: function(e,Dest,Src){
         console.log('Coming from ' + Src + ' going to ' + Dest);
   }
});
```

https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/wiki/Settings#events